# How to repeat box every page?

Tags: pdftex, boxes

I need to repeat a box with the same content on each page, but not how.

attached sample image
[image]

Comment: On *every*, *every* page without exceptions? Also, is that big X supposed to be an image?

Comment: Yeah, X is an image, and without exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; adjust the settings according to your needs:

[image]

The code (needs two or three compilations):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[color=black,opacity=1,angle=0,scale=1]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
  contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,draw,anchor=west,text width=1.2in,minimum height=\textheight] 
    (sidebar)
    at ([xshift=10pt]current page.west)
    {};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north]
    (image) 
    at ([yshift=-20pt]sidebar.north)
    {\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-a}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north,font=\LARGE\bfseries]
    (title) 
    at ([yshift=-20pt]image.south)
    {Title};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north,text width=1in]
    (text) 
    at ([yshift=-20pt]title.south)
    {Some additional text goes here};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```