# Adding background using tikz package

Tags: xetex

I would like to add background to all of my pages, so far I managed to put a background on a single page using this command:

```
\newcommand{\addbackground}[1]{
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=1,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}};
}
```

this is great as my cover page needs his own background. However, for the rest of my pages I would like one const background. is there a way to fix this command to do that?

Comment: maybe the `eso-pic`could help?

Comment: Alternatively, one can use the everypage package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already use `tikz` in your document, we can search for another solution,  like [thisone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270195).
But as suggested by samcarter, just for a background, the `eso-pic` route is simpler and  also much more  light-weight :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{gradient}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```